# Is it possible to replicate behaviour of "flex-end" in :before & :after pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have the following code below which creates a checkbox using `:before` & `:after` and then utilises a hidden `input` to handle the logic of selecting an item. It all works as expected and I'm happy with the behaviour however I'm wondering is it possible to make the checkbox (created in the `:before` & `:after`) to sit at the very right hand side of the wrapper like so:

[image]

I would usually use `flex-end` but that of course then moves the entire label (with the checkbox) to the end of the wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.label.reverse > .label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.label.reverse{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

 .label:before {
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
  }

.label:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   height: 20px;
   content: "";
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .label::after {
    background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label reverse" for="checkbox2">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      Option 1
    </div>  
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a flex item is absolutely positioned it is removed from the flex formatting context. In other words, most flex properties won't work anymore. *(See flexbox spec: [§4.1. Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items))*

Try removing `position: absolute` from the checkbox.

Make three simple adjustments to your CSS code:

```
.label.reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between; /* new; pin items to opposite ends */
  flex: 1; /* new; give container full width of parent */
}

.label:before {
  /* position: absolute; */ /* keep item in flex formatting context */
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.label.reverse>.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.label.reverse {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between; /* new; pin items to opposite ends */
  flex: 1; /* new; give containe full width of parent */
}

.label:before {
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label reverse" for="checkbox2">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      Option 1
    </div>  
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea, good point about `position:absolute`, thats what i did in my answer, i just didnt want to talk to much, just showed him the right code :)

Comment: Explain what you did so that everybody can understand your answer. It's more useful that way. Thanks. @Coja

Comment: Will do that in the future, Thank you for the tip :D @Michael_B

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    width: 200px;
  }
  
  .input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    visibility: hidden;
    
  }
  
  .label-wrapper {
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  
  .label.reverse > .label-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 24px;
  }
  
  .label {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .label.reverse{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    
  }
  
   .label:before {
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      content: "";
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius:4px;
      margin-left:90px
    }
  
  .label:after {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     height: 20px;
     content: "";
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center center;
     background-size: 80%;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .label::after {
      background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
        <label class="label reverse" for="checkbox2">
          <div class="label-wrapper">
            Option 1
          </div>  
        </label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:-

```
label {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}

input {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

html

```
<label for="autologin">Option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="autologin" name="autologin" value="1">
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: To `.label::before` add `left: 170px;`